# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol when using SendInput()

Tags: c, compiler-errors, lnk2019, sendinput

I'm writing a C program that uses the SendInput() function to simulate keystrokes. However, I get the following error when compiling: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SendInput@12 referenced in function _main`. I am using the VisualStudio developer command prompt to compile. Here is my code:

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>

main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("C:/invisible.vbs", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "CreateObject(“Wscript.Shell”).Run “””” ^& WScript.Arguments(0) ^& “”””, 0, False");
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("C:/run1.bat", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "net user administrator /active:yes pass");
    fprintf(fp, "runas /user:administrator wscript.exe \"C:/invisible.vbs\" \"C:/run2.bat\"");
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("C:/run2.bat", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "copy /y nul C:/test.txt >nul");
    fclose(fp);
    system("run1.bat");
    INPUT ip;
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    ip.ki.wVk = 0x50; // p
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    ip.ki.wVk = 0x41; // a
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    ip.ki.wVk = 0x53; // s
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    ip.ki.wVk = 0x53; // s
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    ip.ki.wVk = 0x0D; // enter
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a certain header that I need to include that I am missing, or is there something wrong with my code? If I am missing a header, which one is it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a difference between headers and libraries as well as compilation and linking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) needs link to user32.lib

Comment: How can I link to this library? I tried using `cl test.c /link use32.lib` but I got another error: `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'use32.lib'`

Comment: I got it to work, I realized I put use32.lib instead of user32.lib

Comment: I also change my post, typos :)